# Formatting strings

Tags: c++

You should use either the C++ string object or C-String for this problem. Read content from a file.
The file format is such that in each line: 1) there are three columns, and 2) each column is delimited
by |.
Output each line to stdout. The first column width should be 15, the second column width should be
8, and the third column width should be 6. If the line starts with a #, you should skip it. Moreover,
the second column should be displayed to 2 decimal places.
There might be more than 3 rows; you cannot assume only 3 rows. However, you can assume that
there are only 3 columns.
Sample input

```
#Test file one
C1|c2|c4
Xyz|1.2|100
Abc|5.5|200
```

So, given that program outline (I am not asking for you to write my code! :( ) here are my thoughts about what to do... 
multidimensional array, but there can be more than three rows so with that variable I don't think I could do a multidimensional array because of that.

I also thought about reading in each line, separating it up, formatting it and then printing it out, worrying about only each line at a time. I'm figuring it to be the best way possible, but I'm open to doing anything by suggestions. I think I would do it by using some sort of end of line "delimiter".

The only other problem I can find is that I'm supposed to ignore and skip lines based on if the leading character is a #. I'm not sure how to do that either, I think the ignore() function is a way but as I understand it starts skipping things until your limit is reached or the deliminator is found. I don't think there is a way, using that function, to find the delim character first and then skip everything to the EOL after it.

Comment: Read a line. Decide what to do. Do it. Repeat until done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the information in array, you can read and output as it goes. For example a skeleton could look something like so

```
string line;
ifstream inputStream("data.txt");

while( getline(inputStream, line) ){ //grab line if possible
 std::vector<std::string> tokens = parseLine( line, '|'); //parse line using '|' as delim
 //if !tokens.empty && tokens[0][0] != '#'
   //print tokens[i] accordingly 

}
```

Comment: he has already mentioned in his question that this is his current plan.

Comment: yes you are right, but the comment-line in the input file is what he was confused with, which the above snippet hints on how to achieve the desired result

Comment: When printing the tokens, tokens[i] works? Or, am I needing to introduce a counter per each token it reads in? And, why can't I just cin >> line; and instead of cin stopping at a blank space make it stop at |?

And the <std::string>, do you mean line? Or, is putting string in there going to work?

Also, I'm not quite sure where the tokens are coming from? Your comments indicated that !tokens.empty is what should go there, but it's commented so I'm assuming tokens isn't the term I should use there? It's all a little vague to me.

Comment: @KHill, it was supposed to be a little vague to give you an idea but not implement it for you. When I say tokens[i], I mean print out tokens[0] with its style, then tokens[1] with its style and tokens[2] with its style, since they each have their unique way to being printed. You cannot just `cin>>line` to read a whole line because that's not how cin works, cin reads up till blank space or fails to read at all. The std::vector<std::string> declares a array of string, that the parse function should return. The tokens are coming from the parseLine function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only thing I can't get right is that parseLine is not declared and a cannot convert to bool unary error?

Comment: you need to create the parseLine function your self. It takes a string and a deliminator, and returns tokens. Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ for more info on how to achieve it

Comment: Well, I give up. Thanks for the help, I'll just take a zero for the assignment. This is giving me a headache.

Comment: @KodieHill if you are wiling to quit, then maybe you should take the 0 else you can start a new post with the trouble you are having and we can guide you along. Your choice

Answer (score 2):

Some helpful snippets:

```
std::cout.precision(2)
std::cout << std::fixed << 1.5; // prints 1.50
std::cout << std::setw (10) << "hi!"; // prints "       hi!"
```

For skipping # lines:

```
std::string s;
ifstream input("test.txt");
while(input >> s){
    if(s[0] == '#') continue;
    // other processing
}
```

And here's a way to overload the >> operator taken from a quick google search:

```
struct Time
{
    int hours, minutes;
};
istream &operator >> (istream &is, Time &t)
{
    is >> t.hours;
    is.ignore(1,':');
    is >> t.minutes;
    return is;
}
```

Using this might look like this:

```
Time t;
ifstream input("time.txt"); // A file containing one line: "6:30"
input >> t; //t now has hours = 6 and minutes = 30
```

which you could use to grab each line into a struct as Jerry Coffin has suggested. That should be about everything you need to implement your solution.

Comment: Your answer is the most helpful, however there are a lot of...conflicting? terminology. In one snippet I'm using ifstream and then another I reuse it. So, technically if I piece this together in the correct order I'm running through the input file twice...Another problem I've ran into is that your snippets don't account for the fact that each column isn't the same type all the way down. I don't think there is a way to KNOW that you read in 1.5 into a string and then, based on that knowledge, change it over to int AND expand it to 1.50.

Comment: I understand it's all supposed to be vague, but I've never worked with structs before so it's all a bit over whelming.

Answer (score 0):

Given that each line contains exactly three items, and you may want to skip some lines, I'd:

1. Create a struct of three strings (or whatever) to hold one line of data.
2. Create a `std::vector<your_struct>` to hold the data you read.
3. Read an entire line into a string using `std::getline`.
4. Check if the line starts with `#` (and if so, skip the rest of the loop).
5. Parse the three items out of the line and save them into one of your `struct`s.
6. Push that `struct` onto the `std::vector`.